# Script error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My current script will unlock a range of cells C8:D60.  If this range is already unlocked, the script will cause an error message - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')

How do I test if range is unlocked first and prevent the error message?  Thanks in advance!

```
function UnlockFriday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('al;dskfjlasdjfl;asdfl;jkasf');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
  var allProtections =     spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
  return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C8:D60';
  });
  var protection = matchingProtections[0];
  protection.remove();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function UnlockFriday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('al;dskfjlasdjfl;asdfl;jkasf');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
  var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  var matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function (existingProtection) {
    return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C8:D60';
  });

  if (matchingProtections.length == 0) return; // Added

  var protection = matchingProtections[0];
  protection.remove();
}
```

- By this modification, when the length of `matchingProtections` is 0, the script is finished. By this, your error can be avoided.
- As another approach, when [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is used instead of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), it becomes as follows.

  ```js
  function UnlockFriday() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('al;dskfjlasdjfl;asdfl;jkasf');
    spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
    var allProtections = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    var matchingProtection = allProtections.find(existingProtection => existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'C8:D60');
    if (!matchingProtection) return;
    matchingProtection.remove();
  }
  ```

Comment: Once again...thank you! The modified script and the alternative script both work and prevent the TypeError message.  My spreadsheet is now complete and ready for everyday use.  you are the best!

Comment: @PT109 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.